# What is behavior of NULL parameters to strstr?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, strstr

What is the behavior when a NULL is passed as the parameters in `strstr`?

Given:

```
char * p = NULL;
char * s = NULL;
```

Case 1:  `strstr(p, "Hello");`

Case 2:  `strstr("With my dog", p);`

Case 3:  `strstr(p, s);`

My understanding is that the behavior is undefined and left up to the implementation for all 3 cases.

According to Microsoft Visual Studio documentation, they perform Parameter Validation and handle it there.  [See Remarks section.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z9da80kz.aspx)

We are using C99 on IAR Workbench.

*Background:  Some testing folks are writing unit tests and assigning NULL to the string variables.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ISO C standard says that the behavior is undefined.

Quoting [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), which is a draft of the 2011 ISO C standard, section 7.1.4:

> Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated
>   otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow: If an argument to
>   a function has an invalid value (such as *[...]*,
>   or a null pointer, *[...]*, the behavior is undefined.

The description of `strstr` in 7.24.5.7 says:

> The **strstr** function locates the first occurrence in the string
>   pointed to by **s1** of the sequence of characters (excluding the
>   terminating null character) in the string pointed to by **s2**.

which, in addition to the statement in 7.1.4, says that the arguments have to point to some string (which a null pointer does not).

These statements are similar, if not identical, in the C90 and C99 standards.

Note that "undefined behavior" does not imply that the program will necessarily crash. For example, this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    char *p = strstr(NULL, "");
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("p == NULL\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("p = %p\n", p);
    }
}
```

when compiled and run on my system (Linux, gcc 4.7.2, glibc 2.15) prints:

```
p == NULL
```

probably because `strstr` optimizes the case of an empty string for the second argument. Undefined behavior is an error that need not be detected or diagnosed; it's entirely your responsibility as a programmer to avoid undefined behavior in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much expect a crash for undefined behavior.

The MSFT docs say that for `strstr` parameters: 'If str or strSearch is NULL, the invalid parameter handler is invoked' and, 'The default invalid parameter invokes Watson crash reporting, which causes the application to crash' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ksazx244.aspx).

You can change this, however by using the function _set_invalid_parameter_handler (at least in the MSFT world).  When that function is called, you have to decide how to recover and if the user should be informed or if the program can continue.